# Loop error in tweepy

Tags: for-loop, printing, tweepy

I have been toying with tweepy recently, I am trying to pull the followers and following of a given user.

```
 followingids = []
 followids = []
 userid = "Someone"#sets target

 for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name=userid).pages():#gets the followers for userID
     followingids.extend(page)
     time.sleep(60)#keeps us cool with twitter


  for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends_ids, screen_name=userid).pages():#gets the followers for userID
     followids.extend(page)
     time.sleep(60)#keeps us cool with twitter

 #where weirdness starts 
 print len(followingids), "followers have been gathered from", userid 
 print len(followids), " users are followed by ", userid

 followingusers = api.lookup_users(user_ids=followingids)#ieterates through the list of users and prints them
 followedusers = api.lookup_users(user_ids=followids) #<does not work but above does 


 print "users of following", userid 
 for u in followingusers:
     print u.screen_name


 print "users followed by", userid
 for s in followedusers:
     print s.screen_name
```

The second print for loop gives this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "twitterBot.py", line 30, in <module>
     followedusers = api.lookup_users(user_ids=followids) #<does not work but above does 
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 160, in lookup_users
     return self._lookup_users(list_to_csv(user_ids), list_to_csv(screen_names))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 230, in _call
     return method.execute()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 203, in execute
     raise TweepError(error_msg, resp)
 tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'Too many terms specified in query.', u'code': 18}]
```

both followedusers and followingusers have twitter id numbers, I literally cut and pasted the code for printing so why does the first one work and the second one not work?

Comment: Can you show the code that generate followingids and followids?

Comment: Added, however the code works as it should loading IDs into the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code isn't broken, necessarily.  Twitter [limits you to returning 100 users](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup) with a GET user lookup (which is what `api.lookup_users` does).  Requesting more than 100 will cause the Tweepy error code 18 which you got only for the followed users query, which looks like the user you queried follows more than 100 users but is followed by less than 100.

A simple solution would be to search iteratively through the list of followers/followed users (both to be safe if you want your code to be more robust).  Iterate through every 100 userids and use `api.lookup_users` to only look up a maximum of 100 at a time.